# JPopupMenu action not triggered

Tags: java, swing, popupmenu

Here's (a siplified version of) what I have. (I found the code that way):

```
class CustomPopup extends JPopupMenu {
    public CustomPopup() {}

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible)
    {
        // Case 1:
        //if (visible) super.setVisible(visible);
        // Case 2:
        super.setVisible(visible);
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
    // .../...
    public CustomPanel() {
        setSize(200, 200);
        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ){
                onMousePressed( e );
            }
        });

    }

    public void onMousePressed( MouseEvent e )
    {
        JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();

        pop.add( new AbstractAction( "foo" )
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
            {
                // do stuff
                System.out.println("this is executed");
            }
        });
        pop.show( e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY() );
    }
}

public class TestPopup extends JFrame {
    CustomPanel _pp;
    CustomPopup _cpop;

    public TestPopup () {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(333, 333);
        _cpop = new CustomPopup();
        _pp = new CustomPanel();
        _cpop.add(_pp);

        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ){
                _cpop.show(e.getComponent(), 0, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                (new TestPopup()).setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A popup menu displays a custom panel. When interacting with it, it show a  classical popup menu with a list of choices.

My problem is that the `CustomPopup` doesn't close itself as it should. The culprit is obviously the override of `setVisible`, BUT if I remove the override method (or comment out the condition) I have another problem : the `actionPerformed` method added on `pop` is never called.

In the first case:

1. `CustomPopup` opens
2. I click on something in it
3. The `JPopupMenu` opens **and the `CustomPopup` remains visible**
4. I click on an item of the new menu
5. The `Action` is triggered

In the second case:

1. `CustomPopup` opens
2. I click on something in it
3. The `JPopupMenu` opens **and the `CustomPopup` is hidden**
4. I click on an item of the new menu
5. The `Action` is **not** triggered

My conclusion is that the `CustomPopup` must be visible for the action to trigger, even if I don't really understand why. So my question is: how to keep `CustomPopup` open in a way that doesn't break the default `JPopupMenu` behavior OR how make the action trigger properly with `CustomPopup` hidden?

Comment: Why not `JComponent::setComponentPopupMenu()`?

Comment: @trashgod can you tell me more? How is it solving the problem?

Comment: I don't know that it would. What happens when you try? Also consider the need to check [`isPopupTrigger()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup), as "Popup menus are triggered differently on different systems."

Comment: What happens: nothing more, the action still doesn't trigger. As for the `isPopupTrigger` I think it's irrelevant since I call the `pop.show()` myself in the `onMousePressed`. The problem is not that the menu doesn't show, its that the actions in it are not performed.

Comment: What's calling `onMousePressed`?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Instead of chaining popup menus like you seem to be doing, why don't you use a `JMenu`? What is the purpose of `CustomPanel` in your implementation? If you need a "popup" for displaying components that are not intended to be contained within `JPopupMenu`, use an undecorated `JDialog` and save yourself some headaches.

Comment: @predi I think the `JPopupMenu` was used in the first place to have the show/hide behavior of a context menu. So how would you hide the `JDialog` when clicking outside of it, or when an item from the `JPopupMenu` is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks that the parent of popup must be visible for action triggering (sounds plausible for me). So you made all to get it working, except the last step: close the custom popup by yourself. Here is the code:

```
class CustomPopup extends JPopupMenu {
    public CustomPopup() {}

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible)
    {
        // Case 1:
        if (visible) super.setVisible(visible);
        // Case 2:
//        super.setVisible(visible);
    }
    public void makeInvisible() {
        super.setVisible(false);
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
    // .../...
    public CustomPanel() {
        setSize(200, 200);
        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ){
                onMousePressed( e );
            }
        });

    }

    public void onMousePressed( MouseEvent e )
    {
        JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();

        pop.add( new AbstractAction( "foo" )
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
            {
                // do stuff
                System.out.println("this is executed");
                Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
                if (comp != null && comp.getParent() instanceof JPopupMenu) {
                    JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) comp.getParent();
                    if (popupMenu.getInvoker() instanceof CustomPanel) {
                        CustomPopup cpop = (CustomPopup) popupMenu.getInvoker().getParent();
                        cpop.makeInvisible();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        pop.show( e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY() );
    }
}

public class TestPopup extends JFrame {
    CustomPanel _pp;
    CustomPopup _cpop;

    public TestPopup () {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(333, 333);
        _cpop = new CustomPopup();
        _pp = new CustomPanel();
        _cpop.add(_pp);

        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ){
                _cpop.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                (new TestPopup()).setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```